# How to change spinner background image?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hi i am new to android,I am using spinner background image. The spinner contains four values, and each one has images.If i click the spinner values, the images will be changed in the spinner background. Please help me how can i change the background image when the spinner value is changed?

Comment: please more explain more clear.u want to change spinner background or when select image in spinner u want to update activity background

Comment: Could you please use correct tags and improve your question so that it is a specific one and not a general `write me the code` one... (after 2 month participating you should know how it works...)

Comment: Please tell more about what your problem is, where you are stuck, and/or provide relevant your sources, maybe we could figure out what you're actually trying to achieve. But don't keep posting [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832187/android-spinnner-image) from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Give Id to the parent (Linear or relative) layout of your main.xml file
and in the java file,if the four values of your spinner is Mercury,Venus,Earth,Mars,
then in the Onselected itemlistener,put code like this

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +
          parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Mercury"))
      {
          ll1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.java_j2me);
      }
      if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Venus"))
      {
          ll1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
      }
      if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Earth"))
      {
          ll1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.javaandroid);
      }
      if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Mars"))
      {
          ll1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.party);
      }
}
```